# Read internal storage file android with cordova (resolveLocalFileSystemURL)

Tags: android, cordova

I have search and try many things only to retrieve the content of a file of any path with resolveLocalFileSystemURL

[image: Path]

The file is located in : storage/emulated/0/miniclipld.txt

But I have not access to it, tried :

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL('file:///storage/emulated/0/miniclipld.txt', function(fileEntry){
            fileEntry.file(function(file) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onloadend = function(e) {
                    console.log(this.result); // text
                };
                reader.readAsText(file);
            });
        }, function(err){
            console.error(err);
            //error
        });
```

too tried

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL('/storage/emulated/0/miniclipld.txt', function(fileEntry){
            fileEntry.file(function(file) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onloadend = function(e) {
                    console.log(this.result); // text
                };
                reader.readAsText(file);
            });
        }, function(err){
            console.error(err);
            //error
        });
```

Anyway the returned code is 1 or 5, is the path of the file not correct or something ? Any help appreciated !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was only a typo in the filaname... the following structure is correct. If someone want to know how to read a file from any path in android , use the following code

```
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL('file:///storage/emulated/0/miniclipId.txt', gotFile, fail);

        function fail(e) {
            console.log("FileSystem Error");
            console.dir(e);
        }

        function gotFile(fileEntry) {
            fileEntry.file(function(file) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onloadend = function(e) {
                    var content = this.result;
                    console.log(content);
                };
                reader.readAsText(file);
            });
        }
```

Comment: Thanks - saved me a lot of time trying to fix this Android bug - I prepend "file://" to the fileURI  - window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL("file://"+fileURI, success , fail) in Android and it fixed the issue for me.